# Is there any way to limit the size of the circle while it is being drawn in leaflet-geoman?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cartography, leaflet-geoman

As you may know, in leaflet-geoman there's a function called "drawCircle" that can let you draw a circle having a pivot in the center and expanding the radius with the mouse.
For my usage, I wanted to limit that feature WHILE the circle it's being dragged, because for now all I do is check that the circle isn't too big AFTER the pm:create event.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
       if (e.layer.getRadius() > 400) {
            attivaToast("Circle is too big!", "error", "#e74c3c");
            map.removeLayer(e.layer)
            return;
        }
```

And this is what I want, but I can't do:

```
map.on('pm:someCircleDragEvent' e=> checkCircleSize(e));
```

If you have any ideas, thanks in advance.

PS: I don't want to use Leaflet.draw or other plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fast fix you can call:

```
map.pm.Draw.Circle._syncCircleRadius = function _syncCircleRadius() {
    var A = this._centerMarker.getLatLng();

    var B = this._hintMarker.getLatLng();

    var distance = A.distanceTo(B);
    if(distance < 500){
        this._layer.setRadius(distance);
    }
  }
```

This is a nice idea, I will implement it in leaflet-geoman